# OCZ Onyx SSD will not boot until power turned off and on

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

There is a 64G OCZ Onyx working as the boot drive for my windows 7 box for little over a couple years now. What happens now is that the box will freeze like the HDD has disappeared and the box will not see it (please insert a boot device and hit any key) while booting, nor does it get detected in BIOS until I **turn the power off and on**. Once the power is on, everything is good again.

It first happened about two weeks ago and since then the frequency of occurrences is only raising (happened twice in the last two days). Does this mean a dying HDD or anything else could be causing this potentially? The motherboard, for example?

Windows event logs are empty regarding the issue. The HDD smart data - here it is (too bad OCZ toolbox does not work with Onyx drives).

[image]

I've tried Crystal Disk Info - it hasn't really helped to understand anything - any other suggestions how to diagnose the issue are very welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had a few motherboards at work where the SATA connections fail over time, it might be worth trying a different socket on the motherboard. No guarantees though, it's worth trying the cheap/free fixes first to try a different SATA cable too.